# How to get the list of commits for a file using tags?

Tags: git

I have the list of files, I want to get the list of commits made for each file in particular time frame or using a tag.

Comment: "Time frame" may be problematic because, for example, developer did the change a month ago but he push it to central repository today. Which "time" is relevant for you? About tag - this is just a pointer to specific commit. Which list of commits (somehow related to the tag) you want to get?

Comment: See [git help rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list), in particular the `--since` and `--until` options, and the `<commits>` and `<paths>` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log <commit-range specification> -- path/to/file1 ... path/to/fileN
```

Commit range specification may be quite sophisticated. I'd suggest reading [man git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). If you need just list of commits (sha1 and subject), you may find useful `--pretty=oneline` option of git log.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Manpage of `git-log`

```
OPTIONS
   <since>..<until>
      Show only commits between the named two commits. When either <since>
      or <until> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of the 
      current branch. For a more complete list of ways to spell <since> 
      and <until>, see gitrevisions(7).
```

The following command will show you log of `path/to/file1` from 2016-11-16 10:00 to 2016-11-16 12:00

```
git log $(git rev-list -n 1 --until="2016-11-16 10:00")..$(git rev-list -n 1 --until="2016-11-16 12:00") -- path/to/file1
```

you need add some procedure to check whether there are commits in those time frame.